# dynamically allocate variables in bash

Tags: bash, variables, dynamic

I've encountered a problem in my bash script.
I need to assign new variables according to files in my folder and assign them a number according to the amount of arguments the script gets (whether it's a script or not).
I'm trying to get a script written like this:

```
n_${array[*]}=`arg_count ${array[*]}`
```

while arg_count checks how many parameters a script gets.
for further use, I'm going to change those variables if there's a function with different arguments needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider posting your script?

Comment: `${array[*]}` combines elements in the array with the first-character of IFS, then (when unquoted, as here) splits them apart between all characters in IFS and glob-expands. In its use passing content to `arg_count`, it's very, *very* unlikely to be in accordance with the behavior you actually want to achieve. Consider `"${array[@]}"` (with the quotes) instead.

Comment: Also, see BashFAQ #6 on assigning to variables indirectly:  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Assigning_indirect.2Freference_variables

Comment: ...and, well, if you just want to count the number of elements in an array, that's `${#array[@]}`.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you can use the `declare` builtin to accomplish this, because it is a command whose argument is a string that resembles an assignment.

```
declare "n_${array[*]}=$(arg_count ${array[*]})"
```

However, note that unless you set `IFS` appropriately and the array contents are amenable, the expansion of `${array[*]}` isn't going to be a string that forms part of a valid identifier.

You probably want to either use an associative array,

```
declare -A n
n[${array[*]}]=$(arg_count ${array[*]})
```

or write your code in a programming language that properly supports data structures.

Comment: how would I make IFS amenable?
I tried setting it up but I end up cutting part of the string

Comment: @NatanhelPoliszuk, that depends on which characters can legitimately appear in your data. The default, for reference, is `$' \t\n'`.

Comment: `${array[*]}` produces a single string in which the elements of the array are joined by the first character of `IFS`. By default, that is a space, and a variable name cannot contain spaces.